# Using google spreadsheets with mit2 app inventor

Tags: google-sheets

I want to use google spreadsheet with android. I Tried example program. I created new datasheet. I used example script code. I tried mit2 app program. This program is example program. I also used postman.
Postman show me error.
Postman error page.Postman connection error status 200 OK.

**Postman error message is:**

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <link rel="shortcut icon" href="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/favicon.ico">
            <title>ERROR</title>
            <style type="text/css" nonce="B6c+P2HTW+vClzlpE+anwg">body {background-color: #fff; margin: 0; padding: 0;}.errorMessage {font-family: Arial,sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; font-weight: bold; line-height: 150%; padding-top: 25px;}</style>
        </head>
        <body style="margin:20px">
            <div>
                <img alt="Google Apps Script" src="//ssl.gstatic.com/docs/script/images/logo.png">
            </div>
            <div style="text-align:center;font-family:monospace;margin:50px auto 0;max-width:600px">TypeError: Cannot read property &#39;getSheets&#39; of null (line: 15, file: &quot;denandroid&quot;)</div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

**script code is :**

```
    function doGet(e) {

  return ManageSheet(e);
}

function doPost(e) {
  return ManageSheet(e);
}


function ManageSheet(e) {

  //READ ALL RECORDS
  if ( e.parameter.func == "ReadAll") {
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
    var sh = ss.getSheets()[0]; //  Postman problem line. 
    var rg = sh.getDataRange().getValues(); 
    var outString = '';
      for(var row=0 ; row<rg.length ; ++row){
        outString += rg[row].join(',') + '\n';  
      }
    return ContentService.createTextOutput(outString).setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
  }

   //DELETE SINGLE RECORD
   else if (e.parameter.func == "Delete") {
    var record = e.parameter.id;
    var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  //var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(e.parameter.ID);
    var sh = ss.getSheets()[0];
  //var sh = ss.getSheetByName(e.parameter.SH);
    sh.deleteRow(parseInt(record) + 1);  //makes the correct row to delete (because of header row)
    return ContentService.createTextOutput("Success, requested action completed");
  
}
 
}
```

postman says problem line in script code line 15. ( var sh = ss.getSheets()[0]; //  Postman problem line)

Also I am using turkish language on google sheets. english name Sheet1 turkish language Sayfa1
I tried both names.
but unsuccess.

I am using this line for the connection spreadsheet.

https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyTt9oaz10WuKh0822hBncRoJZAw-D4hcGMwJwdy95l8H_mXfE/exec?ID=18NFZD7vZ-JySbbV7jiZMBpiBsoLJ4IQge9Wk9cL6Z4c&SH=Sheet1&func=ReadAll

Please help.
Thanks

Comment: Problem solved. The problem is the sharing problem. When sharing, it should be (Anyone, even anonymous). google always wanted me to sign in.
When sharing (script code file) must be, In the 1st window, (me and gmail address) should be selected. (Anyone, even anonymous) should be selected in the 2nd window.
sheet name not problem.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The problem is the sharing problem. When sharing, it should be (Anyone, even anonymous). google always wanted me to sign in. When sharing (script code file) must be, In the 1st window, (me and gmail address) should be selected. (Anyone, even anonymous) should be selected in the 2nd window. sheet name not problem